# How to implement future function in R-Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, promise, future

How do I use future function

```
  #Final Report output
  output$repTable <- renderFormattable({
    future({getFinalReportData()}) %...>%   {
      formattable()
    }
  })
```

Using the code above results in the following error:

> Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'as.htmlwidget'
>   applied to an object of class "promise"
>         96: formattable::as.htmlwidget
>         95: func
>         82: origRenderFunc
>         81: output$repTable
>          1: runApp
>
> Unhandled promise error: Operation not allowed without an active
>   reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done
>   from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a reactive expression/value in a future call ([check this article](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html)).

> In addition to the constraints that all futures face, there is an additional one for Shiny: reactive values and reactive expressions cannot be read from within a future. Whenever reactive values/expressions are read, side effects are carried out under the hood so that the currently executing observer or reactive expression can be notified when the reactive value/expression becomes invalidated. If a reactive value/expression is created in one process, but read in another process, there will be no way for readers to be notified about invalidation.

What you can do is for is first bind the reactive expression output to a variable and use this in your future call:

```
 #Final Report output
 output$repTable <- renderFormattable({
    data <- getFinalReportData()
    future(data) %...>% formattable()
 })
```